# ctypes module couldn't find correct free disk space for a NAS partition

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to find free disk space on my NAS box from a remote machine. For this, my Python script is using this:

```
import ctypes
fbytes = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
tbytes = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
path = "<My NAS path>"
success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExW(ctypes.c_wchar_p(path),ctypes.pointer(fbytes),ctypes.pointer(tbytes), None)
free_bytes = fbytes.value
total_bytes = tbytes.value
```

This cannot find the correct values. On my NAS box, I have two partitions. The partition which is shared as a NAS drive has almost 380GB free space, but the other partition has 8GB free space. The above code gives my 8GB free space instead of 380GB.

Comment: What is `success` and `path`? Also, you should pass using `byref` instead of `pointer`.

Comment: You don't provide a concrete example of the `path` you're using, so I'll just quote the only line from the docs that seems relevant: If this parameter is a UNC name, it must include a trailing backslash, for example, "\\MyServer\MyShare\".

Answer (score 0):

The result depends on the value of the `path` variable; on my NAS where I have 12 shares, on 3 partitions, specifying the different one returns the values for the partition that is holding it; i.e.:

```
path = r'\\NAS\photo'
...
print free_bytes # returns 380098863104L
...
...
path = r'\\NAS\docs'
...
print free_bytes # returns 91234780389L
```

Comment: Ideally it should do that. However, in my case it is showing the free space of the other partition. Do you know when can this happen? How to troubleshoot such cases?

Comment: Please do a simple test - instead of the NAS, point it to  local hdd partitions, and see if it reports correctly; I'm speculating it has something to do with the NAS shares config.

Comment: If I give a local path, it works fine. But not when I give a NAS path.